# Can I setup the /tmp folder during setup of a nextflow pipeline?

Tags: nextflow

I want to install What The Phage using nextflow and I'm running into /tmp full issues.
I'm ussing the following command:

```
nextflow run replikation/What_the_Phage -r v1.2.0 --setup -profile local,singularity
```

Is there a parameter that I can give to change the path toward /tmp?

Answer (score 0):

The What_the_Phage pipeline defaults the workdir to `/tmp`, you can change it by via the `--workdir` parameter. Make sure your machine has enough storage space to run the pipeline, or you might have a bad time.

`nextflow run replikation/What_the_Phage -r v1.2.0 --setup -profile local,singularity --workdir <your dir>`